# Return user data with node js in firebase functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

This is my database

[image]

I have a profile page. I just want to get logged-in user data and create endpoint in firebase function.Forexample 2rnWA7TF11gSWxec7MsCA5iRhjw1 logged on I want to fill in the relevant fields

Comment: If I understand correctly that you want to display in your front end (you mention a "profile page" and "fields") some data from the user's node in your database after he/she has logged in, you don't need a Cloud Function to do so. You just need to query your database based on the user's UID after login. Which login mechanism are you using? Mail and password?

Comment: Yes Mail and password. I want to use functions this is necesseary for me

Comment: Can you elaborate in more detail which client platform and how you foresee the flow of events. I guess you refer to an HTTPS Cloud Function.

Comment: Yes I'll create https end point and endpoint return the username,lastname,job etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
  exports.customfunction = functions.firestore.document('Users/userID').onCreate(event =>{     
   // you can do here with your inserted data

   const data = event.data.data(); // updated value
   const previousData = event.data.previous.data(); // before updated value
   //return the event once your operation ends
 })
```

Comment: I guess I should use it on request. I will use the existing value. I do not create it. I actually only need the user uid but I do not know how to access it with the function

Comment: @AhmetSaz are you using http client for accessing user data? if that's the case, then use "functions.https.onRequest(){}"